expo development server creation error.Loaded "env" configuration for the "development" profile: no environment variables specified
I am trying to create an android development server with npx eas build --profile development --platform android but I get this error:
Loaded "env" configuration for the "development" profile: no environment variables specified. Learn more
EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/Users/******/Library/Accounts'
    Error: build command failed.

I tried running the same command again using "sudo" but no change.
